# Trial/Free Cloud service to store a Relational Database

Tags: cloud, relational-database, trial

I need to store a relational Db on the cloud for a college project. Does any1 know of a service that offers a free trial period or even a free student usage (some chance). I already have the application working with a MySQL Db (phpMyadmin), ideally a service that would require very little changes to my app would be the best solution. I have had a look at amazon RDS but there is no trial, I also had a look at Aptana, but a pro version of their IDE is needed ($99).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2's Data-As-A-Service is the best way to suffice your requirement. What you have to do is, just simply create a domain for yourself in stratoslive [1] (demo is the free version available there) and consume its Data-As-A-Service solutions which enables you to create a relational database free of charge to be used in your application. This service would create a mysql database in the Relational Storage Service offered by WSO2. For further details, refer the article located at [2].

[1] https://stratoslive.wso2.com
[2] http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/09/wso2-unveils-its-relational-storage-solutions-wso2-stratoslive

Cheers,
Prabath

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Microsoft SQL Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlazure/default.aspx) is an option?

Comment: thanks I got it sorted using http://xeround.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might check out http://www.iis.net/previewoffers they do include a both SQL Server and MySQL as part of their offers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some Cloud database services, which provides free-trials. Some limits the database records/transaction, while other gives time trial. But worth trying.

[Salesforce's Database.com](http://database.com/)

[SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/)

[Microsoft offers SQL Azure Database](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlazure/default.aspx)

[ClearDB - MySQL powered cloud database](http://cleardb.com/)